# Group By SQL server

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
select vendnm as vendedor,
ref as referencia,
ETILIQUIDO as total 
from pn
where FDATA between #1# and #2#`
```

The problem is that the column `ref` have a lot of different data like `AM0002, FA0003, MO004` and I have to group all of this in just 2 different groups and make a sum.

All data that start with `'FA%'` and the rest of data.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want a separate row for each `vendnm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case` statement, something like:

```
select (case when ref like 'FA%' then 'FA' else 'OTHER' end) as grp,
       sum(ETILIQUIDO) as total
from pn where FDATA between #1# and #2#
group by (case when ref like 'FA%' then 'FA' else 'OTHER' end);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
SELECT vendnm         AS vendedor,
         CASE
            WHEN ref LIKE 'FA%' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
          END       AS ngrp,
       Sum(ETILIQUIDO)AS total
FROM   pn
WHERE  FDATA BETWEEN 1 AND 2
GROUP  BY vendnm,
          CASE
            WHEN ref LIKE 'FA%' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
          END
```